# How to find files that are duplicates of files in a certain folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, deduplication

I need to remove the duplicates in my computer, since i have around 5 copies of every single photo, in different folders. I want to delete the photos that also appear in a certain folder, in witch i sorted a bunch of them. I want it to keep the files in the folder, and also keep duplicates that do not also appear in that folder
Ex:
i want to keep the files on the desktop.

> - C:/Desktop/file1,file3
> - C:/Desktop/2016/file2
> - C:/Backup/file1(2),file4
> - C:/Backup2/file1(3),file2(2),file4(2)

The result should be

> - C:/Desktop/file1,file3
> - C:/Desktop/2016/file2
> - C:/Backup/file4
> - C:/Backup2/file4(2)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: CCleaner's duplicate finder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `dir1` to be the path you want to search and `dir2` to be the *certain folder*:

```
find dir1 -not -path "dir2/*" | grep -F -f <(ls -1 dir2) | parallel rm
```

or, if you only have `xargs` and not `parallel`:

```
find dir1 -not -path "dir2/*" | grep -F -f <(ls -1 dir2) | xargs rm
```

**Example:**

Let's say you want to look in the `C:` drive and the *certain folder* is `C:\Desktop`, then on [cygwin](https://cygwin.org):

```
find /cygdrive/c -not -path "/cygdrive/c/Desktop/*" | grep -F -f <(ls -1 /cygdrive/c/Desktop) | parallel rm
```

on [Git-for-Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io):

```
find /c -not -path "/c/Desktop/*" | grep -F -f <(ls -1 /c/Desktop) | parallel rm
```

on [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about):

```
find /mnt/c -not -path "/mnt/c/Desktop/*" | grep -F -f <(ls -1 /mnt/c/Desktop) | parallel rm
```

Comment: Did not work as expected... (i am probably at fault here) . I used cygwin and $ find /cygdrive/c/dedup -not -path "/cygdrive/c/dedup/test/*" -delete | grep -F -f <(ls -1 /cygdrive/c/dedup/test) and it deleted all files except the ones in /test(the "certain folder")

Comment: No, I made a mistake in placing the `-delete` option before `grep`: this way, all found files are deleted *before* the filter is applied! It should have been `find dir1 -not -path "dir2/*" | grep -F -f <(ls -1 dir2) | parallel rm {}`.

Comment: oh, now testing it

Comment: Had quite some trouble installing parallel and whatever else it required, but now it works ;3! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @cezieu Sorry for posting a dangerous answer in the first place, good thing you tested it out. `parallel` does the same as `xargs`, which is usually available by default, so you should not have bothered.